# dislocker won't compile

Tags: 16.04, encryption, disk

```
----[android@android]------[09:10:49]----~
==> cd dis*
----[android@android]------[09:11:09]----~/dislocker-0.6.1
==> ls
CHANGELOG.md  cmake  CMakeLists.txt  include  INSTALL.md  LICENSE.txt  man  README.md  src
----[android@android]------[09:11:10]----~/dislocker-0.6.1
==> cd src
----[android@android]------[09:11:13]----~/dislocker-0.6.1/src
==> make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
----[android@android]------[09:11:40]----~/dislocker-0.6.1/src
==> sudo apt-get install libfuse-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libfuse-dev is already the newest version (2.9.4-1ubuntu3.1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libidl-2-0 libkeybinder0 liborbit2 python-gconf python-gnome2 python-keybinder python-pyorbit python-vte
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
----[android@android]------[09:11:46]----~/dislocker-0.6.1/src
==> 

----[android@android]------[09:13:46]----~/dislocker-0.6.1/src
==> ls
accesses        config.c         dislocker-file.c      dislocker-metadata.c  inouts           metadata  samples
CMakeLists.txt  dislocker-bek.c  dislocker-find.rb.in  dislocker.rb          logs             ntfs      xstd
common.c        dislocker.c      dislocker-fuse.c      encryption            mbed_install.sh  ruby.c
```

-

```
---[android@android]------[09:17:55]----~/dislocker-0.6.1/src
==> cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:21 (add_definitions):
  Policy CMP0005 is not set: Preprocessor definition values are now escaped
  automatically.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0005" for policy details.  Use
  the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:22 (add_definitions):
  Policy CMP0005 is not set: Preprocessor definition values are now escaped
  automatically.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0005" for policy details.  Use
  the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:23 (add_definitions):
  Policy CMP0005 is not set: Preprocessor definition values are now escaped
  automatically.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0005" for policy details.  Use
  the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:25 (add_definitions):
  Policy CMP0005 is not set: Preprocessor definition values are now escaped
  automatically.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0005" for policy details.  Use
  the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:30 (add_definitions):
  Policy CMP0005 is not set: Preprocessor definition values are now escaped
  automatically.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0005" for policy details.  Use
  the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:109 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindPolarSSL.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "PolarSSL",
  but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "PolarSSL" with any
  of the following names:

    PolarSSLConfig.cmake
    polarssl-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "PolarSSL" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "PolarSSL_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "PolarSSL" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
  if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/android/dislocker-0.6.1/src/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
----[android@android]------[09:18:41]----~/dislocker-0.6.1/src
==> make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
----[android@android]------[09:18:55]----~/dislocker-0.6.1/src
==>
```

Comment: Have you run `cmake .` as advised in the [INSTALL.md](https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker/blob/master/INSTALL.md) file?

Comment: @steeldriver i tried but failed

Comment: That's presumably because your system does not include the prerequisite software - also listed in the INSTALL.md file (in particular `"Headers for PolarSSL/mbedTLS"`)

Comment: https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker/issues/71

Comment: i am looking at it.... hopefully find a answer.... thank you for pointing me to the github page.